Calling a sub-workflow by its fully-qualified name is not working
I created two workflows in Google Cloud Console. The first workflow (= sub-workflow) does the authentication with an external API and returns an access token, the second workflow (= main workflow) calls the subworkflow and does other things with the external API.
I created both workflows in the same project, with the same service account and in the same region.
The sub-workflow runs without errors and returns the access token.
The main workflow YAML looks like this:
main:
  steps:
    - callAuthWorkflow:
        call: projects/{PROJECT_ID}/locations/{REGION_ID}/workflows/my-auth
        result: authResult
    - returnResult:
        return:
            message: "Operation successful"
            data: ${authResult.body}

When trying to call the subworkflow from the main workflow, I get the following error:
Could not deploy workflow: main.yaml:4:15: parse error: in workflow 'main', step 'callAuthWorkflow': incorrect format of the call target 'projects/{PROJECT_ID}/locations/{REGION_ID}/workflows/my-auth'; must be a (fully-qualified) workflow name
        call: projects/{PROJECT_ID}/locations/{REGION_ID}/workflows/my-auth
              ^

 (Code: 3)

What I checked so far:

Both workflows use the same service account. The service account has the role "Workflows Invoker" assigned. I even tested to assign the role "Workflows Admin".

I checked the console to verify the correct fully-qualified workflow name. I entered gcloud workflows list --project={PROJECT_ID} --location={REGION_ID} and got the correct workflow name.



I guess you tried to adapt the syntax described in the official documentation for subworkflows to your case where your subworkflow was already written and already deployed elsewhere. But this syntax works only if the subworkflow is declared at the same time as your main workflow (i.e. in the same file).
For calling workflows already deployed, you have to use the Workflow Execution Connector syntax:
main:
  steps:
    - callAuthWorkflow:
        call: googleapis.workflowexecutions.v1.projects.locations.workflows.executions.run
        args:
          workflow_id: my-auth
          #project_id: ...
          #location: ...
        result: authResult

